# Laravel Wrong Login Redirect

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

So I have the route lsapp.test/firms/1 which isn't available if you are not logged in.

But if I go to that route without being logged in is redirecting me to the login.After I log in it redirects me back to lsapp.test/firms/1, not the dashboard, and I get an error.

I've changed $redirectTo in the controllers to /dashboard but still isn't working.

If I go to /login and login it works.

How I can fix this?

```
 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

```
 public function show($id)
    {
        $employes = Firm::find($id)->employes()->paginate(5);
        return view('firms.show')->with("employes", $employes);
    }
```

Error: Call to a member function employes() on null.

Comment: There we go. This means that `Firm::find($id)` is `null`. Do you have a record in your `firms` table that has an `id` of `$id` (should be `1` in this case)? Note: You should never assume the result of `->find()` exists; there's always a chance it will be `null`, so you should check for existence before trying to access a property, or use `->findOrFail($id)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The findOrFail methods will retrieve the first result of the query; however, if no result is found, a Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException will be thrown.
If the exception is not caught, a 404 HTTP response is automatically sent back to the user. It is not necessary to write explicit checks to return 404 responses when using these methods.

```
public function show($id)
 {
     $employes = Firm::findOrFail($id)->employes()->paginate(5);
     return view('firms.show')->with("employes", $employes);
 }
```

Comment: Nick, this is the 2nd answer of yours I've seen that is a straight code-dump with no explanation; these can be flagged and removed as very low quality, so please start adding explanations to your answers. Edit: 3rd answer now.

Comment: Sorry, I’ll add now.

Comment: That's much better! Always take a second to briefly explaining *why* someone should use the code you posted :)